# Find missing file via commandline

Tags: compositing-nodes, blend-files, command-line, linux

The problem is simple. I created some compositing projects with many input files from different places distributed on the hard disk. I want to render the final projects on another pc, but don't want to restore the original folder hirachy with all the sub folders. So I've planed to copy all raw material into one folder on the 'render pc' and let blender search there for missing files - automatically, because the target OS is non-graphical.
I would be delighted if somebody could help!
Julian

Comment: Can you be more explicit? Show an example of full paths to files on the source machine and the destination path on the destination.

Comment: @glennjackman I'm using some Movie Clip nodes as input. A example path is //.\.\raw\cam4\c4_C0030.mp4 or //.\.\.\footage\nature\treesky.mp4 (at Win). At destination:  //./mixinput/c4_C0030.mp4. Do you mean that?

Answer (score 0):

Using python you can change the filepath stored for every movie clip. You can do this before saving the blend file onto the remote machine by pasting the following into blender's text editor and clicking the run script button.

```
import bpy, os

for m in bpy.data.movieclips:
    m.filepath = os.path.join('//mixinput', os.path.basename(m.filepath))
```

Then when you open the blend file on your remote machine, blender will look for the movie clips in the `mixinput` folder located next to the blend file.

If you want to do it on the remote machine you can add `bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile()` to the end of the above script and save it to a file next to the blend file, then use

```
blender -b myfile.blend -P myscript.py
```

The same can be used to adjust VSE clips by changing the for loop to

```
for m in bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences:
```

or for all images using

```
for m in bpy.data.images:
```